# What is the best way to aggregate Streams into one DISTINCT with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose i have multiple java 8 streams that each stream potentially can be converted into `Set<AppStory>` , now I  want with the best performance to aggregate all streams into one DISTINCT stream by ID , sorted by property ("lastUpdate")

There are several ways to do what but i want the fastest one ,  for example:

```
Set<AppStory> appStr1 =StreamSupport.stream(splititerato1, true).
map(storyId1 -> vertexToStory1(storyId1).collect(toSet());

Set<AppStory> appStr2 =StreamSupport.stream(splititerato2, true).
map(storyId2 -> vertexToStory2(storyId1).collect(toSet());

Set<AppStory> appStr3 =StreamSupport.stream(splititerato3, true).
map(storyId3 -> vertexToStory3(storyId3).collect(toSet());


Set<AppStory> set = new HashSet<>();
set.addAll(appStr1)
set.addAll(appStr2)
set.addAll(appStr3) , and than make sort by "lastUpdate"..

//POJO Object:
public class AppStory implements Comparable<AppStory> {
private String storyId;
private String ........... many other attributes......
public String getStoryId() {
    return storyId;
}
@Override
public int compareTo(AppStory o) {
    return this.getStoryId().compareTo(o.getStoryId());
   }
}
```

... but it is the old way.

How can I create ONE DISTINCT by ID sorted stream with BEST PERFORMANCE

somethink like :

```
  Set<AppStory> finalSet = distinctStream.sort((v1, v2) -> Integer.compare('not my issue').collect(toSet())
```

Any Ideas ?

BR

Vitaly

Comment: How does your `equals` method look like?

Comment: @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        AppStory appStory = (AppStory) o;

        return !(storyId != null ? !storyId.equals(appStory.storyId) : appStory.storyId != null);

    }

Comment: I think something like:       Set<AppStory> dsd = Stream.of(appStr1, appStr2).flatMap(Stream::distinct).sorted((s1, s2) -> Long.compare(s1.getLastUpdateTime(), s2.getLastUpdateTime())).collect(toSet());

Comment: How many elements do you have in each `Spliterator` and is the `vertexToStory` method an expensive one?

Comment: each Spliterator has about 1000 elements , the method vertexToStory convert DB properties into POJO , -  not expensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the parallel overhead is much greater than the actual work as you stated in the comments. So let your `Stream`s do the job in sequential manner.

FYI: You should prefer using `Stream::concat` because slicing operations like `Stream::limit` can be bypassed by `Stream::flatMap`.

`Stream::sorted` is collecting every element in the `Stream` into a `List`, sort the `List` and then pushing the elements in the desired order down the pipeline. Then the elements are collected again. So this can be avoided by collecting the elements into a `List` and do the sorting afterwards. Using a `List` is a far better choice than using a `Set` because the order matters (I know there is a `LinkedHashSet` but you can't sort it).

This is the in my opinion the cleanest and maybe the fastest solution since we cannot prove it.

```
Stream<AppStory> appStr1 =StreamSupport.stream(splititerato1, false)
                                       .map(this::vertexToStory1);
Stream<AppStory> appStr2 =StreamSupport.stream(splititerato2, false)
                                       .map(this::vertexToStory2);
Stream<AppStory> appStr3 =StreamSupport.stream(splititerato3, false)
                                       .map(this::vertexToStory3);

List<AppStory> stories = Stream.concat(Stream.concat(appStr1, appStr2), appStr3)
                               .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
// assuming AppStory::getLastUpdateTime is of type `long`
stories.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(AppStory::getLastUpdateTime));
```

Comment: Parallel distinct is expensive for _ordered_ streams, but for unordered streams, is much more efficient.  (In ordered streams, `distinct()` must preserve the _first_ of equal occurrences, similar to the stability requirement in sorting.)  Toss an `unordered()` into the stream and you'll probably find the parallel performance to be far more attractive.

Comment: You might get better overall performance by using `Stream.toArray()`, followed by either, `Arrays.sort` or `Arrays.parallelSort`, followed by `Arrays.asList`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't guarantee that this would be faster than what you have (I guess so, but you'll have to measure to be sure), but you can simply do this, assuming you have 3 streams:

```
List<AppStory> distinctSortedAppStories = 
    Stream.of(stream1, stream2, stream3)
          .flatMap(Function.identity())
          .map(this::vertexToStory)
          .distinct()
          .sorted(Comparator.comparing(AppStory::getLastUpdate))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: why you use "....map(this::vertexToStory)" ?      all streams "stream1, stream2, stream3" ...have already made transform via map function.  why not use Stream::distinct ?

Comment: Because that allows making it once instead of thrice: just pass the original streams instead of passing 3 "mapped" streams, and let the combined stream do the mapping. Regarding the second part: combining 3 distinct streams doesn't no lead to a distinct stream. You need to use distinct() on the combined stream, to make sure all the elements are unique.

Comment: Maybe you could use Stream.concat instead of stream.of + flatmqp

Comment: I'm not sure which would be more performant, but when I see distinct + sorted, I usually consider replacing both with a collect to a TreeSet.

Comment: @HankD But the distinction and the sorting are based on different fields. So you can't use a `TreeSet`.